# Existence of principal G-bundle given an associated vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

I am wondering if the following is true.

Let $G$ be a Lie group, $V$ a vector space, $\rho$ a representation of $G$ on V, and $\pi: E\rightarrow M$ a vector bundle with fibre $V$. Does there exist a unique (up to principal bundle isomorphism) principal $G$-bundle, such that $E\cong P\times_\rho V$, where $P\times_\rho V$ is the vector bundle associated to $P$ and the representation $\rho$ on $V$?

I know that every $\mathbb{K}$ vector bundle of rank $n$ is associated to a principal $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{K})$ bundle, but is this unique up to isomorphism? Is this also true if we have any subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb{K})$? Or even any Lie group with representation on the fibre vector space?

Comment: What can you say about the vector bundle $P\times_{\rho}V$ if $\rho$ is the trivial representation?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Can I say something about it in general then? It does not necessarily have to be a trivial vector bundle, right?

Comment: Right, if $E$ is non-trivial, it is not of the form $P\times_{\rho}V$ for any principal $G$-bundle $P$. Given a representation $\rho$, one could ask which vector bundles $E$ take the form $P\times_{\rho}V$ for some principal $G$-bundle $P$. This will depend on the representation and is a difficult question to answer in general.